# Angular Webpack typeerror: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'kind')

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

All of a sudden my Angular app is getting an error when building the application.

```
TypeError: C:\Users\c\dev\privacy\node_modules\@fortawesome\angular-fontawesome\fesm2020\angular-fontawesome.mjs: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'kind')

./node_modules/primeng/fesm2020/primeng-api.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\c\dev\privacy\node_modules\primeng\fesm2020\primeng-api.mjs: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'kind')

./node_modules/primeng/fesm2020/primeng-button.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\c\dev\privacy\node_modules\primeng\fesm2020\primeng-button.mjs: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'kind')

./node_modules/primeng/fesm2020/primeng-calendar.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\c\dev\privacy\node_modules\primeng\fesm2020\primeng-calendar.mjs: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'kind')
```

I have 40 more lines like that.
Yesterday I deployed the app without any single problem, today went for a quick deploy and all of the errors came up.

Using Angular 13

Tried updating the dependencies, even the angular version but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the dependencies had a faulty update but they fixed it within 24 hours apparently.
Reverted every change/test that I made and suddenly, everything is now working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have a solution, but I ran into this same thing today. So, I'll add my details in case it triggers something for someone.

Also using `angular 13`. I tried updating to `angular 14` as well, but that didn't work.

I also go this for `angular-fontawesome` and only one other package. The other package is a custom package in a private repo. But, I have no issues with that private repo in other projects yet. This is only affecting one out of three angular projects so far. I'm going through the differences between them later.

It's not something we changed. It just started happening today. It started happening on our build server. To be sure it wasn't something we changed, I rebuilt a branch that we haven't touched in a month and it fails with the same error. I was finally able to recreate it locally by deleting `node module`, `package lock` and clearing the `npm cache`.

That's all I know so far. I will update as I learn more.

Update:
In `tsconfig.json`, I had:

```
"target": "es5"
```

I changed that to match another app that was not experiencing the problem:

```
"target": "es2015"
```

and it works. I can't explain why this just became a problem today though.

Comment: It was some dependency issue as expected, They updated today and without changing a single thing, It's now working